# LuaLaTeX Element with attribute values find

Tags: luatex, lua

I have need to find `<ELEMENT attr="A2">` and print in PDF. How to achieve this. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
xml = require('luaxml-mod-xml')
handler = require('luaxml-mod-handler')
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
sample = [[
<DATA>
  <TITLE>Quantum vacuum ç under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</TITLE>
  <NAME="name" />
  <VERSION="1" />
  <VARIABLES>
    <TEST>
      <ELEMENT attr="A1">123.000000001</ELEMENT>
      <ELEMENT attr="A2">789.000000001</ELEMENT>
    </TEST>
  </VARIABLES>
</DATA>]]
treehandler = handler.simpleTreeHandler()
x = xml.xmlParser(treehandler)
x:parse(sample)
tex.sprint(treehandler.root["DATA"]["TITLE"])

tex.sprint(treehandler.root["DATA"]["VARIABLES"]["TEST"]["ELEMENT"])

\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

It is possible both direct UTF and `&#x00E7;` to work my XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to work with `luaxml-domobject` library, as it provides higher level interface and fixes one fatal isssue that `simpleTreeHandler` has - it doesn't keep the correct element order in mixed order XML. It makes it suitable for HTML, for example. I've learned this hard way when I used it for the [odsfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/odsfile?lang=en) package. It cannot keep correct order of formatting elements in table cells. It is the original part of LuaXML library and while it seems easiest to use, when you bounce into this issue, it is something that cannot be fixed. It is best to avoid it. Really.

Anyway, I will show solution for both `simpleTreeHandler` and `DOM Object`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
xml = require('luaxml-mod-xml')
handler = require('luaxml-mod-handler')
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}

sample = [[
<DATA>
  <TITLE>Quantum vacuum ç under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</TITLE>
  <NAME="name" />
  <VERSION="1" />
  <VARIABLES>
    <TEST>
      <ELEMENT attr="A1">123.000000001</ELEMENT>
      <ELEMENT attr="A2">789.000000001</ELEMENT>
    </TEST>
  </VARIABLES>
</DATA>]]
treehandler = handler.simpleTreeHandler()
x = xml.xmlParser(treehandler)
x:parse(sample)
tex.sprint(treehandler.root["DATA"]["TITLE"])

for _, element in ipairs(treehandler.root["DATA"]["VARIABLES"]["TEST"]["ELEMENT"]) do
  if element._attr["attr"] == "A2" then
    tex.sprint(element)
  end
end


\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

`reehandler.root["DATA"]["VARIABLES"]["TEST"]["ELEMENT"]` is a table, so you need to loop around it and find the correct attribute using `element._attr["attr"] == "A2"`.

This is the version that is rewritten for the `DOM Handler`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<DATA>
  <TITLE>Quantum vacuum ç under mixed boundary conditions: the case for curved spacetime</TITLE>
  <NAME="name" />
  <VERSION="1" />
  <VARIABLES>
    <TEST>
      <ELEMENT attr="A1">123.000000001</ELEMENT>
      <ELEMENT attr="A2">789.000000001</ELEMENT>
    </TEST>
  </VARIABLES>
</DATA>]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
tex.sprint(dom:query_selector("TITLE")[1]:get_text())

for _, element in ipairs(dom:query_selector("VARIABLES TEST ELEMENT")) do
  if element:get_attribute("attr") == "A2" then
    tex.sprint(element:get_text())
  end
end


\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

You can parse the XML file using `domobject.parse()` function. It returns object that contain various methods. The most useful is `dom:query_selector` which supports CSS like selectors. For example

```
dom:query_selector("TITLE")
```

will return all `<TITLE>` elements in the document. You can select the first one using usual Lua table index. This selected object still has support for DOM methods, so you can retrieve text using the `get_text` method:

```
dom:query_selector("TITLE")[1]:get_text()
```

The second query loops over all `VARIABLES/TEST/ELEMENT`. It retrieves the `attr` attribute from each of them using the `get_attribute` method, and prints contents of the element where the attribute matches value `A2`.

This is the result:

[image]

Regarding this question:

> It is possible both direct UTF and `&#x00E7;` to work my XML?

I guess yes? What issue do you have?

Comment: About entities: When i have tested with `simpleTreeHandler` its showing the error `! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.`

Comment: Using `Dom Object`, I have stored `title` value in `variable Title` . How to print afterwards. Example: `Title = (dom:query_selector("TITLE")[1]:get_text())`. Need to print in `maketitle`.

Comment: @Balaji ah I see. it is another thing fixed in the DOM library.

Comment: @Balaji just don't put parentheses around: `Title = dom:query_selector("TITLE")[1]:get_text()`

Comment: How to use any characters using RegEx in Lua?

Comment: @Balaji put `%` character before it. Like `string.gsub("hello-world", "%-", ":")`